# How can I deal with a difficult coworker who is related to my manager?

Tags: resignation

I work in a small office, where computers and desks are shared. This creates a very close environment. I get on well with my work colleagues, but one person in particular is causing me concern. On a daily basis she is responsible for the majority of the mistakes our team makes. After dealing with a couple of angry customers in a row, or having to take time out to fix a complex problem, I am more likely to make a mistake myself because of the added stress.

On top of this, my colleague is always complaining, which often builds into rants, and twice she has lost her temper in a dangerous way, which I have had to gently confront her about. I know she is making some attempts to control her temper, but the ranting is still difficult to deal with. She won't be reasoned with. Although we are colleagues I've noticed she tries to order me about and often tells me to ignore something the manager has said or criticises me for following staff policy if she feels she knew a better way to handle a situation.

When my colleague is in a good mood we get on very well, and I am aware she has emotional problems. However things have got much worse in the past few weeks, and last week something she said had me trembling in fury. I have never lost my temper at work, but this was the first time I came close.

She is related to our manager who got her the job in the first place. Our manager also hates confrontation so I know that I can't expect any help from her.

Is there a way to solve this by going to management, or should I start looking for a new job?

Comment: Does your manager's boss know that your manager's relative makes causes problems for your group by making lots of mistakes, and sometimes losing her temper in a dangerous way, that your manager doesn't do anything about it, and that good employees think about leaving? I think he or she should.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Workplace. I've edited your question slightly to avoid running afoul of the close reasons. I believe my edit doesn't go against your original intent, but you'll be the judge of that. Feel free to roll back changes if you don't agree with them. Cheers

Comment: Voted to close. With the limited information available and the constraints you give, there is no other solution than leaving. Your question needs to have practical answers to be on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

If your manager is where the buck stops as far as hiring and firing goes, there is not much you can do other than loving it or leaving it. But if there is someone above her, like an HR department, you can take the issue up with them as a relative working for a supervisor is a conflict of interest and a definite no-no in structured US companies.